# Calculate Day difference in 2 dates input datetimepicker with jQuery?

Tags: jquery, laravel

Help me for calculate the days between two dates format dd/mm/yyyy

```
<input class="form-control datetimepicker" type="text" name="leavefrom" id="leavefrom">
<input class="form-control datetimepicker" type="text" name="leaveto" id="leaveto">
<input class="form-control" name="numberofdays" id="numberofdays" type="text">
```

Comment: please share your code and your attempts to solve the problem

Comment: @OMR please help me for get difference

Answer (score 0):

Try this in your controller.

```
use Carbon\Carbon;

$parseto = Carbon::parse($request->leaveto);
$to = Carbon::createFromDate($parseto);
$from = Carbon::parse($request->leavefrom);
$duration = $to->diffInDays($from);
```

Comment: I want jQuery part for it @Firdaus Nasir